# Custom Report Item not showing up in the web browser

Tags: reporting-services

I followed the steps listed on these MSDN pages:

- [Creating a Custom Report Item Run-Time Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345254.aspx)
- [Creating a Custom Report Item Design-Time Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345225.aspx)
- [How to: Deploy a Custom Report Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345230.aspx)

I have now a custom report item that works fine in Visual Studio 2010, but does not show up when rendering the report in a web browser. The Windows Event Log is saying:

> "Report Server (MSSQLSERVER12) cannot load the CRITest extension."

CRITest is the name I gave my CRI.

I developed the same object in Visual Studio 2008, because I thaught that SSRS 2012 does not support .NET 4.0 (in the ReportingServicesService.exe.config you find SupportedRuntime=2.0). Result: the object cannot be dropped into a report developed with Visual Studio 2010, because the Common7/IDE/PrivateAssmblies needed for Reporting Services has another version number.

Does anyone have a good suggestion?